# Unable to connect to port 445 at one location. All other subnets can connect

Tags: server-message-block, share

I have run into a weird issue that i just cant seem to figure out. One of our servers is a file server and is accessible by \servername\ or by \X.X.X.X\ from every remote location aside from the one in question. I am able to ping the file server, and confirmed port 139 is open by telnet X.X.X.X 139 as well as RDP on port 3389 but receive the below error message when I try to use port 445.

The error message i am receiving : Could not open connection to the host, on port 445: connect failed.

Netstat shows that the server is listening on port 445 for all other subnets. I have also created an inbound windows firewall rule to allow all connections over port 445. I was unable to find any ACLs that may be blocking on the edge as well. Interestingly enough, something has to be blocking this as if the user connects to a client vpn, they are able to connect to the share. Does anyone have any suggestions to further isolate where the issue is?

Comment: If you can connect to the server on port 445 from the same subnet, then the problem is a firewall somewhere. Either the Windows Firewall or a network firewall or router. Additionally, there's already a built-in firewall rule to allow SMB traffic inbound to port 445. You don't need to create a "custom" rule for it. Delete your "custom" rule and use the built in rule.

Comment: What makes you certain that the issue lies on the server rather than on the client side or the client network?

Comment: I can connect to the file server on a different subnet, but all machines within this specific one are having issues. Thanks for the advice, I will delete the custom rule. I cant see why a network firewall would block this traffic from this subnet, but allow others but i will continue to check if thats the case. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I believe its on the server or network, because i have tried connecting to the file share from 3 different machines on the same subnet with the same issue. That leads me to believe it is one or the other.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Can you connect to the server on port 445 from the same subnet as the server?

Comment: I can connect on the same subnet as the server, but a separate remote subnet i could not. I believe I may have found a routing issue which was causing this. Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

I would start by disabling the Windows firewall (temporarily) altogether. Also, you can do a packet capture on the server to verify that the attempts to tcp/445 are getting there at all... something like `windump -ni1 port 445 and host 192.168.1.10` assuming that 192.168.1.10 is the client machine and interface `1` is the server NIC in question (run `windump -D` to get a list of NICs on the server). You can get [WinPcap and WinDump](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/) from Riverbed.

Comment: I downloaded WinDump and tested it with two ports. I see connections when i use your command for ports 139, but nothing with 445. This would essentially point this to being a network firewall issue on edge now, correct?